# How can I make 2 functions onclick work in JS?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I try to create a simple traffic light system for a project however once i use the      `onclick="maakGroen();maakRood();">`  the 2nd function does not work....

This is my code

```
<input type="button" name="Licht" value="Licht" onclick="maakGroen();maakRood();">
```

```
<script>
  var Licht = document.getElementById('Licht');
  function maakRood() {
    Licht.src = "stop1.png";
  }
  function maakGroen() {
    Licht.src = "stop2.png";
  }
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do? The second function is immediately undoing what the first one did. You only see the result after both functions execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an event listeners, in the example below, you can replace `querySelector` with `getElementByID`; more info on the developer site or you can find tutorials on w3schools
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener.

```js
document.querySelector(".elementname").addEventListener("click", doStuff)

function doStuff() {
    maakGroen();
    maakRood(); 
}
```

If you don't like this, then you can simply make a new function with all the code from `maakGroen();maakRood();` pasted into it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout()` to delay the second function so you can see the first function's change.

```
<input type="button" name="Licht" value="Licht" onclick="maakGroen();setTimeout(maakRood, 1000);">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a third function with both functions in it and use a timeout just like @Barmar said.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like that ?
*(your question is really unclear!)*

```js
const trafficLights = document.querySelectorAll('.traffic-light')  

trafficLights.forEach(Tl => Tl.addEventListener('click', permuteTLcolor ))

function permuteTLcolor()
  {
  if (this.classList.contains('red'))    { this.classList.replace('red','green');    return }
  if (this.classList.contains('green'))  { this.classList.replace('green','yellow'); return }
  if (this.classList.contains('yellow')) { this.classList.replace('yellow','red');   return }

  this.classList.add('red')
  }
```

```css
.traffic-light {
  display       : inline-block;
  width         : 2.6em;
  height        : 8em;
  border-radius : .7em;
  background    : #1c1641;
  margin        : 1em;
  padding-top   : .3em;
  cursor        : pointer;
  }
.traffic-light:hover {
  background    : #372c69;
  }
span {
  display       : block;
  width         : 2em;
  height        : 2em;
  border-radius : 50%;
  margin        : .4em .3em;
  box-sizing    : border-box;
  border        : .2em #97b2cc42 solid;
  }
.traffic-light > span:nth-of-type(1) { background: #441111; }
.traffic-light > span:nth-of-type(2) { background: #36360d; }
.traffic-light > span:nth-of-type(3) { background: #0b270b; }

.traffic-light.red    > span:nth-of-type(1) { background: #fc1515; border: 0; }
.traffic-light.yellow > span:nth-of-type(2) { background: #f3f314; border: 0; }
.traffic-light.green  > span:nth-of-type(3) { background: #28e728; border: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="traffic-light red">
  <span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
<div class="traffic-light green">
  <span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
<div class="traffic-light yellow">
  <span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
<div class="traffic-light red">
  <span></span><span></span><span></span>
</div>
```